# Count Years of Employment

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to find a way using sql to update the employment enddate for any user if the second position was started the next day after the first position was ended. thanks in advance!

Here's my data:

```
DECLARE @EmploymentDateRanges TABLE
        (
            ID INT IDENTITY (1, 1),
            StartDate DATETIME,
            EndDate DATETIME
        )

INSERT INTO @EmploymentDateRanges
VALUES ('11/1/2018', null)

INSERT INTO @EmploymentDateRanges
VALUES ('8/24/1995', '10/31/2018')

INSERT INTO @EmploymentDateRanges
VALUES ('5/25/1990', '8/24/1994')
```

As you can see, the startdate in the first insert statement is the next day after the enddate in the second insert statement.

My expected result is to update only the enddate in the second insert statement and set it to null.

The end date in the third insert statement shouldn't be changed since the different between the enddate in the third statement and startdate in the second statement is more than 1 day

Comment: I've tried this but, it didn't work:
 UPDATE EmploymentDateRanges
 SET EndDate = GETDATE()
 WHERE ID in  (SELECT ID 
     FROM EmploymentDateRanges 
     WHERE EndDate IS NOT NULL 
                 GROUP BY ID, StartDate, EndDate 
     HAVING DATEDIFF(DAY,MIN(EndDate), MAX(StartDate)) < 1 
     )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can use a self `join` and `dateadd`:

```
update e
set e.enddate = null
from EmploymentDateRanges e 
   join EmploymentDateRanges e2 on dateadd(day, 1, e.enddate) = e2.startdate
```

This adds 1 day to the `enddate` and sees if there are any corresponding records with that `startdate`.  If so, it updates the `enddate` to `null`.

---

Another option would be to use `exists`:

```
update e
set e.enddate = null
from EmploymentDateRanges e 
where exists (select 1
              from EmploymentDateRanges e2
              where dateadd(day, 1, e.enddate) = e2.startdate)
```